# Why my default terminal path on WSL is set to the document where VScode is installed?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote

I am connecting to my WSL by VSCode, but if I create a new terminal, it is opened under the Windows document where VSCode is installed. The screen capture of the terminal path:

[image]

I have tried to modify the setting "`terminal.integrated.cwd`" to "`${fileDirname}`" or "`${workspaceFolder}`", but neither of them works.